# Watch host styles in Stencil js component

Tags: stenciljs

I would like to figure it s there a way to watch changing styles on a component's parent element.
For example:

```
 <custom-modal style="visibility: hidden"> </custom-modal>
```

I need to watch on 'visibility' style inside `<custom-modal>` and do some actions once this style is being changed.

@Watch decorator only monitors state and properties.

Comment: You can observe **inline** style changes with the MutationObserver API. But there is no native code to observe CSS changes.